# Calculating Hit Accuracy score in a game

Tags: c#, unity, leaderboards

I'm currently in the process of making a scoreboard for my game. One of things I would like to display is the players accuracy in the amount of hits they had in game. However, I have never done this before and I've no idea how to go about doing this.

Is there a commonly used algorithm out there that can help me calculate this, or has someone found a way to calculate this fairly easily?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: ShotsHit / ShotsFired * 100? Or did I mis-understand the question..?

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen Nah I think that's just it, you should post this as answer.

Comment: The 'algorithm' is just the addition of one to the accuracy variable, executed on every hit, i.e. `accuracy++;`.

Comment: -1 If you have to ask *how to calculate a percentage*, you've definitely not done enough research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, it's simply just:

```
float hitAccuracy = ShotsHit / ShotsFired * 100;
```

Basically just every time the player fires a shot, increment ShotsFired by one and if the shot hits the target, increment ShotsHit by one.

Of course, there's one problem with this. If Player A fires 100 shots of which 99 hits the target, he would lose to someone who has shot only one shot which hitted the target. This is not necessary a problem, but if it is, could you give us more details about your game?

Comment: Depending on the type of `ShotsFired` and `ShotsHit` you might want to cast them first to avoid integer division. Also I don't consider the number of shots fired being an issue. Such games usually show both values and only consider values for rankings, if a given minimum number of shots have been fired. One more thing to note, which might be more serious issue: If you're able to hit multiple targets, it's possible to get more than 100% (or back to 100%) rather easy (prominent example: Battlefield 3's shotguns).

Comment: @Mario: Why? If you hit two targets with one shot, `ShotsHit` would be incremented by one, or the variable ought to be renamed `TargetsHit`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thought about counting actual hits rather than shots that hit.

Answer (score -1):

it depends on how much of each hit the timing is, if it shows marvelous or perfect on all of the shots, it is 100% accuracy, there is usually 5 or 6 ratings, from most timed to least timed, the least would be a miss, and the more of a certain timing the less the accuracy would be, all greats, would not be the same accuracy as like an all perfect or an all marvelous.